# MSBuild Target BeforeBuild not Executing

Tags: msbuild, build-script

I seem to have a situation where code that I put into the BeforeBuild target is not successfully executing.

Here is what I have:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild" >
    <Message Text="Before Build" />
</Target>
```

I can’t see the message output in the build log when the build runs.  Is there something wrong with the way I’ve formatted this, or does it have to be in a specific place in the script?  Am I even looking in the correct place for these messages?

EDIT: changing the importance to high seems to make no difference

Comment: How do you launch the script? Where do you look for the message? Try adding the attribute Importance="high" to message task.

Comment: I'm looking in the build log - is this the wrong place?

Comment: It's the right place. Could you paste the project file content here?

Comment: I think I found the problem.  I think the TFSBuild.proj target was being overridden by the local project .proj file (which has a blank BeforeBuild and AfterBuild)

Answer (score 5):

See the answer to this question
[MS-Build BeforeBuild not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352228/ms-build-beforebuild-not-firing)

You just need to move the BeforeBuild target so that it appears after the line that imports Microsoft.CSharp.targets.

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly override the Before build target. The easiest way to do it is to insert the override before  tag, or declare this task as DefaultTargets.

```
<Project DefaultTargets="DesktopBuild" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="3.5">
    <!-- Override TFS build targets and run custom made ones -->
  <Target Name="BeforeCompile" DependsOnTargets="VersionAssemblies"></Target>
  <Target Name="AfterCompile" DependsOnTargets="GetTime;RunTests;CreateHTMLReport;Mail"></Target>
  <Target Name="AfterDropBuild" DependsOnTargets="RemovePrevContent;CopySrcBinaries;ZipBinPackages;CopyAllContent;RemoveBindings"></Target>

</Project>
```

Comment: When I override BeforeCompile, it works.  But overriding BeforeBuild does not.  Specifying DefaultTargets doesn't seem to matter - if there's something in the .proj file for the solution, it seems to use that as a preference.